# How is the space of $\mathcal{H}_{x}$ and $\mathcal{H}_{\xi}$ connected?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform

It might be a silly question, but I really don't know. There're 3 things I want to ask:

1. For example, with Schrödinger's equation $i\partial_{t}\psi = H\psi$ , where $\psi_{n}(x)$ are the eigenfunctions of $H$, what does it mean to apply a Fourier transformation on $\psi_{n}(x)$? What does $\mathcal{F}(\psi_{n})(\xi)$ represent in physics?
2. Consider in the 1d case, with $H = -\partial_{xx}+V(x)$ specified, what can we say about functions $\psi_{n}(x)$ and $\mathcal{F}(\psi_{n})(\xi)$?
3. How are spaces of $\mathcal{H}_{x}$ and $\mathcal{H}_{\xi}$ related with respect to the operator defined below?

**The definition of the operator** Fix an arbitrary linear operator $A:\mathcal{H}_{x}\rightarrow\mathcal{H_{x}}$ which could be expanded to (perhaps called quantization in physics, but I'm not sure)

$$[A\psi](x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int e^{i(x-y)\xi} \ a(x,y) \ \psi(y) \ \mathrm{d}y \ \mathrm{d}\xi$$

We can define $G_{A}:\mathcal{H}_{x}\times\mathcal{H}_{\xi}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by:

$$G_{A}(\psi,\varphi) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\iint e^{ix\xi} \ a(x,\xi) \ \overline{\psi(x)} \ \varphi(\xi) \ \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}\xi$$

Does the so defined, $G_{A}$ , have any significant usage in physics? Or is it only a mathematical construct (by now)?

This looks like a 'weighted' inverse Fourier transformation of $\varphi(\xi)$ makes inner product with $\psi(x)$.

Comment: The pdf for finding position in a certain interval becomes the pdf for finding momentum in a certain interval.

Comment: @ConnorBehan pdf?

Comment: @Filippo I think he means a Partial Differential Equation by a pdf.

Comment: I mean probability density function.